# Jasper Reports set a different java bean collection data adapter for a sub report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Could anyone point me in the direction of how to set a different data adapter for a sub report? I just can't seem to find an example / tutorial that uses a different connection.  Essentially I'm creating a report based on a JavaBean Collection and I was struggling to iterate a nested collection of objects so I thought I would create a sub report which uses a different javabean collection data adapter set to the ListArray object contained by the javabean object in the main report (I hope that's clear?).

So for example I may have object Supplier which is passed as a JavaBean collection data adapter to the main report.  The Supplier object has a ListArray member Products (List  prods = new ListArray () type thing).  I couldn't get the initial datasource to pick this 'sub object' up so I thought I'd create a sub report and point it at the prods List as a different javabean collection data adapter.

I seem to be having problems though.  Initially I created the report separately (no problems here) and tried to add it to the main report.  the report runs fine but I can't work out how to set the connection properties to work when adding it as a subreport though ?  So instead I tried creating a new report when adding the sub report.  This seems to work but when I go to add the fields (Dataset and query dialog, javabeans tab) I get a 'Class Not Found by com.jaspersoft.studio_6.0.3.final' error.

I can't seem to find any examples of how to set the sub reports data adapter ?

Many thanks if you can help or point me to a relevant tutorial/ set of documentation.  I'm using the eclipse add on by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you should have a field named "Products" in your main report.

You pass it to your subreport via the Data-Source-Expression property. E.g.

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{Products})
```

You should leave the Connection-Expression property empty.

If that doesn't work, you should check if your classes are in JasperStudio's classpath. You can add the classes by setting the correct buildpath in the project properties.